# Performance issue with pyspark job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using pyspark / spark sql  for performing very simple tasks. Data size is very less, highest being 215 MB. 90% of the data sources sizes are less than 15 MB. We do filtering, crunching and data aggregations and resultant data is also less than 5 MB for 90% of data. Only 2 data results are 120 MB and 260 MB.
Main hot-spot is coalesce(1) operation as we have requirement to produce only one file. I can understand 120 MB and 260 MB gziped file generation and writing taking time. But generation and writing less than 5MB file should be fast. When I monitor job I can see lot of time is taken by coalesce and save data file. I am clueless why it should take 60-70 secs for generating and writing 2-3 MB file.

**Configuration:**
I have achieved some performance gain with fat executors of 3 vcores per executor. I am using 1 master 3 worker cluster with 4 core node.

Regards

Manish Zope

Comment: Spark is a distributed processing engine. The coordination of nodes, jobs, and eventually tasks requires some considerable time. If you want to process 215 MB of data, Spark is not the right tool. You can do so with pandas or just plain python.